# Add folder instead of individual files as payload to bootstrapper wix

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.8

I want to add an .exe to my bundle. This executable depends on 100+ files.
IS there a way to add the folder as payload instead of adding each file individually ?

If not, what are the other options to bundle this executable in wix bootstrapper.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [HarvestDirectory Target](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html)

For a good example how to use it have a look at [this](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/wix-example-harvest-directory)